# Map duplicate rows in Pandas dataframe by vlalue of a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe with 2 columns `[id][string]`, I need to know which lines are duplicates of which lines based on the value of the column `[string]`.
My dataframe has thousands of rows but only 2 columns.

**Sample of the input dataframe:**

```
id,string
0,"A B C D"
1,"D B C D E Z"
2,"A B C D"
3,"Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z"
4,"D B C D E Z"
5,"A B C D"
```

In this sample, rows **0, 2, 5** are duplicates of each other. Also rows **1 and 4** are duplicates of each other. (id is unique)

**I want the following output:**

```
[["0","2","5"]],["1","4"]]
```

Comment: Why do you want the ids as strings in the output when they're integers in the dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use groupby and a listcomp.

```
>>> df
   id                   string
0   0                  A B C D
1   1              D B C D E Z
2   2                  A B C D
3   3  Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z
4   4              D B C D E Z
5   5                  A B C D
>>>
>>> [l for l in df.groupby('string')['id'].apply(list) if len(l) > 1]
[[0, 2, 5], [1, 4]]
```

If you really want strings in the result, use

```
>>> [[str(x) for x in l] for l in df.groupby('string')['id'].apply(list) if len(l) > 1]
[['0', '2', '5'], ['1', '4']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter by length of lists after aggregate `list` per `string` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
s = df.assign(id = df['id'].astype(str)).groupby('string')['id'].apply(list)
out = s[s.str.len().gt(1)].tolist()
```

If already `id` are strings:

```
s =  df.groupby('string')['id'].apply(list)
out = s[s.str.len().gt(1)].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is using `duplicated`:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated('string',False)].groupby('string')['id'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).tolist()).tolist()

# [['0', '2', '5'], ['1', '4']]
```

if there's no need to change 'id' type:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated('string',False)].groupby('string')['id'].apply(list).tolist()

# [[0, 2, 5], [1, 4]]
```